# CSS Notification design trouble in some HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, notifications

I try to create a notification which show top of the screen. I have issue my notification message is overlapping on each other. [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg2Ki.jpg)
I want to make text line break. But here also issue is my notification is not hide properly and view like this [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkCAL.jpg).
I want to make like this same [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Z7v.jpg) which properly close or hide and line breaks.

Thank you!

```js
$("#close").click(function() {
     $("#myTosterror").hide();
   });
```

```css
#myTosterror {
        top:0;left:0;
        border-radius:0;
        font-size:14px;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        background:#f44336;
        min-height:50px;
        line-height: 1.4px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        height:35%;
        z-index:1100;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:16px 36px;   
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        cursor:default;color:#fff;
        } 
        .cssanimations.csstransforms #myTosterror{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
        -webkit-animation: slideDown 5.5s 0.5s 1 ease forwards;
        -moz-transform:    translateY(-50px);
        -moz-animation:    slideDown 5.5s 0.5s 1 ease forwards;
    }

    #close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 9px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      background: url(images/close.png);
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .cssanimations.csstransforms #close {
      display: none;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
@media only screen and (max-width:420px){
    #myTostwarning,#myTostnotice,#myTostSuccess,#myTosterror{
    
    }  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myTosterror">Sare Jaha Se Achcha Hindustan Hamara Hum Bulbule hai eske ye gulsita hamara. sare jaha se achcha hindustan hamara.<a id="close">[close]</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your initial issue but decided to write something really quick that would actually give you toast-like notifications. I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but it's a trivial amount of code for a far better experience.

jQuery

```
var toasts = $('#toasts'),
    toast = $('.toast'),
    duration = 500,
    autoDismissDelay = 3000;

function addToast(config){
  var close = config.autoDismiss ? '' : '&times;';

  var toast = $([
    '<div class="toast ' + config.type + '">',
    '<p>' + config.message + '</p>',
    '<div class="close">' + close + '</div>',
    '</div>'
  ].join(''));

  toasts.append(toast);

  setTimeout(function(){
    toast.addClass('show');
  }, duration);

  if(config.autoDismiss){
    setTimeout(function(){
      toast.find('.close').click();
    }, autoDismissDelay);    
  }
}

$(document).on('click', '.toast .close', function(e){
  var toast = $(this).parent();

  toast.addClass('hide');

  setTimeout(function(){
    toast.remove();
  }, duration);
});

$('#add').click(function(){
  // show auto-dismiss error
  addToast({
    type: 'error',
    autoDismiss: true
    message: 'My auto-dismiss toast message'
  });

  // show closable warning
  addToast({
    type: 'warning',
    message: 'My toast message'
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#toasts {
  min-height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

#toasts .toast {
  background: #d6d8d9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  transform: translateY(15%);
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out, transform .5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  will-change: opacity, transform;
  z-index: 1100;
} 

#toasts .toast.success {
  background: #26d68a;
}

#toasts .toast.warning {
  background: #ffa533;
}

#toasts .toast.info {
  background: #2cbcff;
}

#toasts .toast.error {
  background: #f44336;
}

#toasts .toast.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out, transform .5s ease-in-out;
}

#toasts .toast.hide {
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 30px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#toasts .toast .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 16px;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="add">Toast Me!</button>

<div id="toasts"></div>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/ajLvjm)

Comment: Thank you @dysfunc but really I just live my notification and try to created based my question might you understand what I want to say. You code is also good but it bit much better when you make it without btm press event. Because I add this toast or notification in php echo ..

Comment: the button is there for demo purposes. you can use echo to render the `.toast` element inside the `.toasts` container. here's an example rendering inline https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaeOVG

Comment: Thank you for that you help me..But it not disappear or hide after some specific seconds or time. Please update last.

Comment: It didn't hide after you clicked the "x"? I just looked at both codepens and it works on all browsers

Comment: I want it must auto hide after 5 second and hide `x` this close button

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes like changed the `line-height` to `14px` which is your fontSize. That was the reason why its was overlapping. This value you can increase if you want more spacing btw lines. Close button is also placed.

```js
$("#close").click(function() {
     $("#myTosterror").hide();
   });
```

```css
#myTosterror {
        top:0;left:0;
        border-radius:0;
        font-size:14px;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        background:#f44336;
        line-height:14px;
        min-height:50px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        height:35%;
        z-index:1100;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:16px 36px; 
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        cursor:default;color:#fff;
        } 
        .cssanimations.csstransforms #myTosterror{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
        -webkit-animation: slideDown 5.5s 0.5s 1 ease forwards;
        -moz-transform:    translateY(-50px);
        -moz-animation:    slideDown 5.5s 0.5s 1 ease forwards;
    }

    #close {
     position: absolute;
right: 36px;
top: 30px;
/* background: url(images/close.png); */
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
    }
    .cssanimations.csstransforms #close {
      display: none;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
@media only screen and (max-width:420px){
    #myTostwarning,#myTostnotice,#myTostSuccess,#myTosterror{
    
    }  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myTosterror">Sare Jaha Se Achcha Hindustan Hamara Hum Bulbule hai eske ye gulsita hamara. sare jaha se achcha hindustan hamara.<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close">X</a></div>
```

Comment: @Raghuvans checked it. Not able to see what you shared above

Comment: @Raghuvans I checked your site...but i could find the error msg. How i can get the error msg?

Comment: Remove the `data-href` attr and try. This was mine `<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close">X</a></div>`

Comment: We made the answer based on the snippet you provided only.If any change is there, please update the Question

Comment: i guess your keyframes is causing the issue. Instead of translateY(-50px); can you try translateY(-100%); and see

Comment: What is  it? is it related to this one?

Comment: @Raghuvans i am not that good in PHP. You beeter google first and then ask in SO

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line-height and add box-sizing:border-box to the #myTosterror. And then I removed the text-indent on the close button and moved it a little to the left.

```js
$("#close").click(function() {
     $("#myTosterror").hide();
   });
```

```css
#myTosterror {
        top:0;left:0;
        border-radius:0;
        font-size:14px;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        background:#f44336;
        min-height:50px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-y:auto;
        height:35%;
        z-index:1100;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:16px 36px;   
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        cursor:default;color:#fff;
        } 
        .cssanimations.csstransforms #myTosterror{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
        -webkit-animation: slideDown 5.5s 0.5s 1 ease forwards;
        -moz-transform:    translateY(-50px);
        -moz-animation:    slideDown 5.5s 0.5s 1 ease forwards;
    }

    #close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 36px;
      top: 9px;
    
      background: url(images/close.png);
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .cssanimations.csstransforms #close {
      display: none;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
        10%, 90% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
@media only screen and (max-width:420px){
    #myTostwarning,#myTostnotice,#myTostSuccess,#myTosterror{
    
    }  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myTosterror">Sare Jaha Se Achcha Hindustan Hamara Hum Bulbule hai eske ye gulsita hamara. sare jaha se achcha hindustan hamara.<a id="close">[close]</a></div>
```

Comment: I don't see this when I run the code. Did you make any changes like adding a parent to `#myTosterror`?

Comment: i guess your `keyframes` is causing the issue. Instead of `translateY(-50px);` can you try `translateY(-100%);` and see